# node.js cluster, redirecting the childs stdout to file breaks data

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, redirect, cluster-computing, stdout

The task is:

1. Cluster creates workers
2. Each worker loads some remote data line by line and output them to its own process.stdout
3. The output of the whole cluster is redirected to file

Expected result: all lines from all workers are concatenated to resulting file

Actual result: on some machines the result is such as expected, on others the result is interlaced.

Tested on 0.10.47 and 0.12.7 nodes under Ubuntu OS. On two machines under Ubuntu 16.04.2 the result is good. On one under Ubuntu 14.04.5 is interlaced.

I need help to understand this situation and fix it on 14.04.

cluster.js:

```
var cluster = require("cluster");

cluster.setupMaster({
    exec: "./worker.js"
});

cluster.fork();
cluster.fork();
```

worker.js:

```
var cluster = require("cluster");
var fs = require("fs");

var workerId = cluster.worker && cluster.worker.id || 1;
var stream = fs.createReadStream("./data" + workerId + ".log");

stream.on("end", function () {
    process.exit();
});

stream.pipe(process.stdout);
```

You need two files in the same folder named data1.log and data2.log with data to read:

```
$ wc -l data*
     9260 data1.log
   111636 data2.log
   120896 total
```

The piping always gives good result:

```
$ node cluster.js | wc -l
120896
```

The redirection to file gives good result only on Ubuntu 16.04 but never on Ubuntu 14.04. Even more on Ubuntu 14.04 it gives every time different results:

```
$ node cluster.js >result.log; wc -l result.log
114135      <= MUST BE 120896
$ node cluster.js >result.log; wc -l result.log
110136      <= MUST BE 120896
```

The redirection to file for addition always gives good result:

```
$ rm result.log
$ node cluster.js >>result.log; wc -l result.log
120896
```

Note that resulting file is lesser than original. It has less lines and even less bytes. So I suppose that lines from different workers are rewriting each other.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should avoid calling `process.exit()` because of the problems it can cause when you have data buffered to be sent somewhere. `process.exit()` ends the process pretty much immediately.

In this particular case, it could very well be that `process.stdout` has not completely flushed its internal buffer (for when `process.stdout` writes are *async*) before the process exits.

My suggestion would be to allow the worker process to exit naturally by simply disconnecting the (unused) IPC channel in the worker via `process.disconnect()` and removing the `process.exit()` in the worker. This should allow `process.stdout` to drain/flush completely before the process exits.

Comment: Thank you for `process.exit` warning, I'll take it into account.

But I don't think that the on exit buffering is the cause of the problem. The node's internal buffer is about 64k. But in this case we lose dozens of mb.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem one must explicitly set piping mode in master code:

```
var cluster = require("cluster");

cluster.setupMaster({
    exec: "./worker.js",
=>    silent: true
});

for (var i = 0; i &lt; 2; i++) {
        var worker = cluster.fork();
=>        worker.process.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
=>        worker.process.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
}
```

I think the reason for such differences in the behaviour of the same code on different versions of ubuntu is in the linux kernel file handle buffer implementations.

Comment: using `silent` will pipe to `/dev/null`, I think there has to be a different setting to use